# What's a proper way to use set_alert_notify to wake up main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, libtorrent-rasterbar

I'm trying to write my own torrent program based on libtorrent rasterbar and I'm having problems getting the alert mechanism working correctly. Libtorrent offers function

```
void set_alert_notify (boost::function<void()> const& fun);
```

which is supposed to

> The intention of of the function is that the client wakes up its main thread, to poll for more alerts using pop_alerts(). If the notify function fails to do so, it won't be called again, until pop_alerts is called for some other reason.

so far so good, I think I understand the intention behind this function. However, my actual implementation doesn't work so good. My code so far is like this:

```
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(_alert_m);
        session.set_alert_notify([&]() { _alert_cv.notify_one(); });
        while (!_alert_loop_should_stop) {
            if (!session.wait_for_alert(std::chrono::seconds(0))) {
                _alert_cv.wait(ul);
            }
            std::vector<libtorrent::alert*> alerts;
            session.pop_alerts(&alerts);
            for (auto alert : alerts) {
                LTi_ << alert->message();
            }
        }
```

however there is a race condition. If `wait_for_alert` returns `NULL` (since no alerts yet) but the function passed to `set_alert_notify` is called before `_alert_cw.wait(ul);`, the whole loop waits forever (because of second sentence from the quote).

For the moment my solution is just changing `_alert_cv.wait(ul);` to `_alert_cv.wait_for(ul, std::chrono::milliseconds(250));` which reduces number of loops per second enough while keeping latency low enough.

But it's really more workaround then solution and I keep thinking there must be proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to record the notification. It should be protected by the same mutex that owns the condition variable.

```
bool _alert_pending;

session.set_alert_notify([&]() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(_alert_m);
    _alert_pending = true;
    _alert_cv.notify_one();
});
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(_alert_m);
while(!_alert_loop_should_stop) {
    _alert_cv.wait(ul, [&]() {
         return _alert_pending || _alert_loop_should_stop;
    })
    if(_alert_pending) {
        _alert_pending = false;
        ul.unlock();
        session.pop_alerts(...);
        ...
        ul.lock();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `condition_variable::wait` overload which takes lambda afaik, but I could probably work around that. But this code would make lambda in `set_alert_notify` block until next `.wait()` call is reached (in the next iteration), correct?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait . As to blocking, yes, but you can relinquish `ul` in last `if` to limit blocking in main thread to only a few instruction at a time.

Comment: yeah that's page I've open too, there are to signatures `void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock );` and `template< class Predicate >
void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock, Predicate pred );`, none of those two seems to match your `_alert_cv.wait([&]() {
         return _alert_pending || _alert_loop_should_stop;
    })`... though I didn't try to compile it so maybe it will work?